# Append return values to list in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

My test step creates 5 worker threads to upload a file to a server and returns the server HTTP response codes for each thread.
I would like to append those to a list of response codes for each step.

```
TC001_Single_User_Upload
   [Documentation] Uploading single file by single user
   ${result}       single user test file upload    test_file.txt    test1   test
   Append To List  @{RESPONSE_LIST}    ${result}
   ${result}       single user test file upload    test_file.txt    test1   test
   Append To List  @{RESPONSE_LIST}    ${result}
   log variables
   log many     @{RESPONSE_LIST}
```

My current log files shows this :

```
20171127 13:59:01.911 - INFO - @{RESPONSE_LIST} = [ ]
20171127 13:59:01.911 - INFO - @{result} = [ <Response [201]> | <Response [201]> | <Response [201]> | <Response [201]> | <Response [201]> ]
```

Q: why is my @{RESPONSE_LIST} empty?

Comment: For those coming to the question wondering how to append to a list: the `Append To List` keyword is part of the [Collections library](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first argument to `Append to list` needs to be a list object. When you use `@`, it's the same as if you took each element in the list and made it a new argument.

The solution is to change the `@` to `$`:

```
Append To List  ${RESPONSE_LIST}    ${result}
```

From the [robot framework user guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#list-variables):

> When a variable is used as a scalar like ${EXAMPLE}, its value will be used as-is. If a variable value is a list or list-like, it is also possible to use as a list variable like @{EXAMPLE}. **In this case individual list items are passed in as arguments separately.**

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the above solution if you want to append a single value to a list.
In case if you want to append a list to an existing list you can change the **'$'** before **{result}**.

So the solution will be like :

```
Append To List    ${list}    @{list2}
```

Assuming the list is declared as follows:

```
*** Variables ***
@{list}    1    2    3    4
@{list2}    5    6    7    8
```

Then you can append the list inside the testcases as shown below:

```
*** Test Cases ***
    Log To Console    ${list}
    Append To List    ${list}    @{list2}
    Log To Console    ${list}
```

This will append all the contents of the **list2** into **list**.
Hope this helps !!!!